# Filter OUTER APPLY column in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I currently have a complex SQL query which is inserted into a temp table. The query includes an `OUTER APPLY` as not all returned records will apply to the result set.

I also need to use the `OUTER APPLY` columns in the `WHERE` clause to filter results but also include the results which do not apply into the `OUTER APPLY` .e. All Outer APPLY results = 1 and non-outer apply results.

This is a simple version of the query layout:

```
INSERT INTO #temp (X, Y, Z, O1, O2)
SELECT 
    X Y Z
FROM T1 
INNER JOIN T2, T etc.
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT O1, O2 FROM XYZ…) OATable
WHERE
    OATable.O1 = 1 -- I tried just adding “IN (1, NULL)” but this 
still excludes the results.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Platform: SQL Server 2012+

Thank you

Comment: I'm intrigued by the actual query; the answers so far both seem good, but I don't think we (potential answerers) can really judge if we're answering usefully based on your very simplified query. If you are able to post the full query, please could you do so? It might help get a more perfect answer.

Comment: Some sample data would also be helpful, perhaps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't compare directly to `NULL` because nothing equates to `NULL` (not even `NULL` itself). That precludes using `IN` here. Instead, just use an `OR` statement:

```
INSERT INTO #temp (X, Y, Z, O1, O2)
SELECT
    X, Y, Z,
FROM T1 
INNER JOIN T2 ON ...
OUTER APPLY (SELECT O1, O2 FROM XYZ…) OATable
WHERE
    OATable.O1 = 1 OR OATable.O1 IS NULL
```

That assumes that `O1` is a `NOT NULL` column in `XYZ`.

Comment: Did you test this?  I did.  If 01 is not null then OATable.O1 IS NULL will always be false.  Even if 01 is nullable then it will still only find actual values of null.  This does not "also include the results which do not apply into the OUTER APPLY".

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer from Tom H adresses the stated question
But I think this might be what you are actually looking for

```
SELECT X Y Z, OATable.*
FROM T1 
INNER JOIN T2, T etc.
LEFT  JOIN XYZ as OATable 
        on OATable.O1 = 1
```

In the answer from Tom you would need a literal OATable.O1 IS NULL (from my findings)
And that is not going to happen if the column is defined as not null
OATable.O1 IS NULL in an outer apply would only find literal value of null even if the column allows null

In this answer you get the left side with no match on OATable  O1 = 1

Comment: I agree with your instinct that OUTER APPLY is unlikely to be the correct approach, but I'm not sure about your justification for why. I think @TomH's answer probably will work, and you might be misunderstanding OUTER APPLY a little. (not sure though!)

Comment: @StuartJCuthbertson then test - i did

Comment: I'm definitely concerned by your LEFT JOIN condition, which is matching on a constant so will match all left hand side rows. This seems unlikely to be correct, I think there may be a join condition hidden in the OP'S real query that we haven't been shown yet.

Comment: @StuartJCuthbertson EXACTLY - that may be what the OP is looking for.  "I also need to use the OUTER APPLY columns in the WHERE clause to filter results but also include the results which do not apply into the OUTER APPLY".  I said might be looking for.

Comment: I'll test when I have access and time to do so, if it's still needed then. I think your answer might be improved by disclosing the results of your tests...

Comment: @StuartJCuthbertson What part of you never going to get an outer apply  match on OATable.O1 IS NULL if that column that is defined at not null (nullable) is not clear?  That is my understanding, verified with test, and communicated clearly (in my opinion)

Comment: See https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx. Quote: " OUTER APPLY returns both rows that produce a result set, and rows that do not, with NULL values in the columns produced by the table-valued function." So the column definition of OATable.O1 is irrelevant. The result set could show Null values from an OUTER APPLY, just like it could from a LEFT JOIN, and Tom's query is finding the rows that did not produce a result set.

Comment: However since APPLY is intended for use with table valued functions, I do agree with you that a JOIN is more likely to be correct. The left join you have used is closer to being a CROSS JOIN (cartesian).

Comment: @StuartJCuthbertson This is not productive.  I tested.   Don't care to debate it with you.

Comment: That's fine, but remember that you and I are not the only audience here.

Comment: @StuartJCuthbertson And I fail to see how this is productive to an extended audience.  Comments are not a chat room.  You are not asking for clarification.  You are asserting something you have not tested is not correct.   If you have different tested findings then I suggest you post another answer.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are trying to achieve:

```
CREATE TABLE #T1 ( X INT, y INT, z INT );
INSERT  INTO #T1
        ( X, y, z )
VALUES  ( 1  -- X - int
            , 2  -- y - int
            , 3  -- z - int
            );
CREATE TABLE #t2 ( a INT, b INT );
INSERT  INTO #t2
        ( a, b )
VALUES  ( 2  -- a - int
            , 5  -- b - int
            );
CREATE TABLE #xyz ( a1 INT, a2 INT );
INSERT  INTO #xyz
        ( a1, a2 )
VALUES  ( 1  -- a1 - int
            , 20  -- a2 - int
            ),
        ( NULL, 30 );

SELECT  Insertdata.X
        , Insertdata.y
        , Insertdata.z
        , Insertdata.a
        , Insertdata.b
        , Insertdata.a1
        , Insertdata.a2
INTO    #temp
FROM    ( SELECT    INQ.X
                    , INQ.y
                    , INQ.z
                    , INQ.a
                    , INQ.b
                    , O.a1
                    , O.a2
            FROM      ( SELECT    X
                                , y
                                , z
                                , a
                                , b
                        FROM      #T1
                                INNER JOIN #t2
                                ON y = a
                    ) AS INQ
                    OUTER APPLY ( SELECT    a1
                                            , a2
                                    FROM      #xyz
                                ) AS O
            WHERE     a1 = 1
                    OR a1 IS NULL
        ) AS Insertdata;

SELECT  X
        , y
        , z
        , a
        , b
        , a1
        , a2
FROM    #temp;
```